# Is there a way to query using TSQL what package/tier a Azure SQL server is running on?

Tags: azure-sql-database

For instance I would like to know whether the instance I'm connecting to is running on S0, S1, S2... from a TSQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following query:

```
SELECT  d.name,   
     slo.*    
FROM sys.databases d   
JOIN sys.database_service_objectives slo    
ON d.database_id = slo.database_id;
```